# Is a `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE` size determined on initialization or does it change over time?

Tags: tensorflow

When setting a `tf.data.Dataset` method uses `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`, does it choose the quantity at initialization? Or does it constantly check the available resources and update over time?

For example, `tf.data.Dataset`'s `prefetch` method can use `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE` to determine how large the prefetch buffer is. Is this determined as soon as the `prefetch` object is created? Or does the `prefetch` constantly update this value depending on how much memory is available?

The current version of [the documentation for AUTOTUNE](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental#AUTOTUNE) and [the `dataset` class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) provide very little information on this. There is [an issue open to improve its documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21070).